# I have problems in booting with a yaffs2 fs

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, embedded, bootloader, u-boot

I am trying to boot an embedded system using yaffs2 fs.
This is the bootargs I used:

console=ttyO0,115200n8 androidboot.console=ttyO0 ip=off mem=256M rootwait=1 rw root=1f09 rw rootfstype=yaffs2 init=/init

An I got this when booting kernel:

```
[    3.160095] yaffs: dev is 32505865 name is "mtdblock9" rw
[    3.165802] yaffs: passed flags ""
[    3.480407] VFS: Mounted root (yaffs2 filesystem) on device 31:9.
[    3.486877] devtmpfs: error mounting -2
[    3.491546] Freeing init memory: 244K
[    3.495422] Failed to execute /init.  Attempting defaults...
[    3.502258] Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
[    3.515350] Backtrace: 
[    3.518005] [<c001803c>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [<c0504850>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[    3.526885]  r7:00000013 r6:c003f498 r5:c0739350 r4:c0739350
[    3.532867] [<c0504838>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c05048b8>] (panic+0x64/0x198)
[    3.540954] [<c0504854>] (panic+0x0/0x198) from [<c0008818>] (init_post+0x84/0xd4)
[    3.548919]  r3:fffffffe r2:00000004 r1:00000080 r0:c05f5690
[    3.554901] [<c0008794>] (init_post+0x0/0xd4) from [<c06a02fc>] (kernel_init+0xf4/0x124)
[    3.563446]  r5:c06dbf94 r4:c0738400
[    3.567230] [<c06a0208>] (kernel_init+0x0/0x124) from [<c003f498>] (do_exit+0x0/0x6ac)
```

I have also tried with other init scripts (/system/bin/sh) but I still have the same problem.

I tryed also with ramdisk image And I got this log from kernel :

```
[    3.171234] omap_rtc omap_rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 01:24:39 UTC (946689879)
[    3.180786] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    3.190429] yaffs: dev is 1048576 name is "ram0" rw
[    3.195587] yaffs: passed flags ""
[    3.199371] List of all partitions:
[    3.203063] 1f00             128 mtdblock0  (driver?)
[    3.208435] 1f01             128 mtdblock1  (driver?)
[    3.213775] 1f02             128 mtdblock2  (driver?)
[    3.219116] 1f03             128 mtdblock3  (driver?)
[    3.224426] 1f04            1920 mtdblock4  (driver?)
[    3.229766] 1f05             128 mtdblock5  (driver?)
[    3.235076] 1f06            5120 mtdblock6  (driver?)
[    3.240417] 1f07            5120 mtdblock7  (driver?)
[    3.245727] 1f08           61440 mtdblock8  (driver?)
[    3.251068] 1f09          187904 mtdblock9  (driver?)
[    3.256408] b300         7875584 mmcblk0  driver: mmcblk
[    3.262023]   b301          200781 mmcblk0p1 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000mmcblk0p1
[    3.270751]   b302         7671037 mmcblk0p2 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000mmcblk0p2
[    3.279449] No filesystem could mount root, tried:  yaffs2
[    3.285247] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(31,9)
[    3.294036] Backtrace: 
[    3.296661] [<c001803c>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [<c0504850>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[    3.305541]  r7:c05f5f18 r6:00008000 r5:c0739350 r4:c0739350
[    3.311553] [<c0504838>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c05048b8>] (panic+0x64/0x198)
[    3.319641] [<c0504854>] (panic+0x0/0x198) from [<c06a0df4>] (mount_block_root+0x1e8/0x228)
[    3.328430]  r3:00000000 r2:cf81df58 r1:cf81df58 r0:c05f59c8
[    3.334411] [<c06a0c0c>] (mount_block_root+0x0/0x228) from [<c06a194c>] (initrd_load+0xb4/0x338)
[    3.343688] [<c06a1898>] (initrd_load+0x0/0x338) from [<c06a0fcc>] (prepare_namespace+0xcc/0x1cc)
[    3.353027]  r5:c06ce068 r4:c06ce05c
[    3.356842] [<c06a0f00>] (prepare_namespace+0x0/0x1cc) from [<c06a02f8>] (kernel_init+0xf0/0x124)
[    3.366149]  r5:c06dbf94 r4:c0738400
[    3.369964] [<c06a0208>] (kernel_init+0x0/0x124) from [<c003f498>] (do_exit+0x0/0x6ac)
[    3.378295]  r5:c06a0208 r4:00000000
```

I don't undestand the cause of this problem.
Since I am not well initiated to this topics, could anyone help me find the cause? 
is there any kernel option to add to have more details about the cause or missing details in bootargs ??

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try giving root partition in command line argument options where init resides. For example. /dev/sda - give whatever your root partition is.

Comment: The init file is contained in the Ramdisk that's why I did the second attempt with kernel+ramdisk with the correct path to the init file. with no result.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience.
Use option inband-tags when mounting from u-boot.

setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mtdblock9 rootflags=inband-tags rw rootfstype=yaffs2